# Adafruit Feather M0 WiFi - ATSAMD21 + ATWINC1500 Firmware updater

Tags: wifi, adafruit, firmware, feather

I have a Adafruit Feather M0 WiFi - ATSAMD21 + ATWINC1500 that indicates the firmware installed is too old for the Wifi101 library (Version 0.16.1).  I have been trying to do a firmware update but when I run the Wifi101 Firmware updater, the GUI indicates that there are no compatible boards connecter.  The board I have selected is the Adafruit Feather M0.  I tried selecting the MKR1000 and the GUI seemed to think that was okay, but after starting the FW update fails.    Which board should I be selecting to get the Firmware Update running?

Per the comment below, I should have mentioned that I did follow the instructions at https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-wifi-atwinc1500/updating-firmware.  One of the pictures showed the board as Adafruit Feather M0, which is what I do have selected, however the WiFi101 Firmware Updater GUI says the board is unsupported.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-wifi-atwinc1500/updating-firmware

Comment: did you notice "If you are using a Feather M0 or WINC1500 breakout, don't forget to update the pins as necessary with setPins()!"?

Comment: In the picture above, partially obscured by the board selection dialog, the WiFI.setPins(8,7,4,2); line can partially be seen.  I believe the message above 'No supported board connected', seems more to do with the Adafruit Feather M0 being selected than the pin configuration.

Comment: try it with older version of the fw updater, before they added update for the NINA fw and board selection